# How to create a JavaScript loop to display an output 100 times

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I’m doing an exercise for high school. The exercise is to create an input and the input needs to be displayed 100 times ( 1) input 2) input 3) input, etc..) and you are not allowed to do it manually; you need to create a loop.

This is what I have so far. I tried googling it for an hour, but I didn't find anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS example</title>

    <style>
      body{font-size: 130%; background-color: teal; color: yellow}
      input, button {font-size: 90%;}
      #output {font-weight: bold; color: blue}
    </style>

    <script>
      function getText(id){
        var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
        return text;
      }

      function showReply(id, reply){
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = reply;
      }

      function reply(){
        var textFromUser = getText("myTextField");
        var str = something;
        showReply("output", reply);
      }
      var something = [
        [var text = "";]
        [var i;]
        [for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {]
        [reply += i + ")" + textFromUser;}]
      ]
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>What does a function say?</h1>
    <p>Write some text in the text field and press the button.</p>

    <input type="text" id="myTextField">
    <button onclick="reply()">click?</button>

    <p> Reply: <span id="output"></span> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far to debug your script? If you open your browser's _developer tools_ and view the _console_, you'll see some error messages that will point you to some issues with your current code. Namely, the syntax/format of your `something` array and `for` loop aren't valid.

Comment: w3schools.com is a wonderful resource that I still reference after 10 years. Specifically, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an element and append to your output container using a *for* loop. Try this:

```js
function getText(id){
  var text = document.getElementById(id).value;
  return text;
}

function showReply(id, reply){
  let container = document.getElementById(id);
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = reply;
  container.appendChild(p);
}

function reply(){
  var textFromUser = getText("myTextField");
  
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    showReply("output", textFromUser);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h1>What does a function say?</h1>
<p>Write some text in the text field and press the button.</p>

<input type="text" id="myTextField">
<button onclick="reply()">click?</button>

<p> Reply: <div id="output"></div> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` is used as a counter. If you want to change how many times it loops, just change the *i<=num*.

```
for (var i=1; i<=100; i++){
   show_reply();
}
```

I suggest you to check [this post](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) on [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools).

Answer (score 0):

I've made two files, one for HTML and the other for JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function getText(id) {
    let text = document.getElementById(id).value;
    return text;
}

function showReply(id, reply) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = reply;
}

function reply() {
    let textFromUser = getText("myTextField");

    let i;
    let span1 = document.getElementById("output")
    let usert = ""
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        usert += "<br>" + textFromUser
    }
    span1.innerHTML = usert
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS example</title>
    <style>
      body{font-size: 130%; background-color: teal; color: yellow}
      input, button {font-size: 90%;}
      #output {font-weight: bold; color: blue}
    </style>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>What does a function say?</h1>
    <p>Write some text in the text field and press the button.</p>

    <input type="text" id="myTextField">
    <button onclick="reply()">click?</button>

    <p> Reply: <span id="output">dd</span> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different potential solutions for this type of question. Choose the flavor you like and put your own spin on it.

```
function showReply(id, reply){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = reply.join('<br>');
}

function reply(){
    var textFromUser = getText('myTextField');
    var outputs = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        outputs.push(`#${ i } ${ textFromUser }`)
    }

    showReply('output', outputs);
}
```